# PassThrough Geometry Shader Not Working

Tags: opengl, glsl, geometry-shader

I am using FragmentShader and VertexShader at present, and works absolutely fine. I cannot get my geometry shader working. I am absolutely new to it, below is what I have tried.

I am using VBO, lighting and textures along with some geometry, but it works fine before using GeometryShader. the only thing I have changed is the variable names as I had to get the input in the geometry shader and give the output. So I have appended 1 at the end of those variable names those which will go out from geometry shader to the fragment shader.

Also I have added headers starting with # which were earlier not there. I am using GL_TRIANGLES to draw.

VertexShader

```
in vec4 position; 
in vec4 color1;
in vec4 normal; 
in vec2 texCoord; 

uniform sampler2D Tex1; 

uniform int use_texture;

out vec4 pcolor;

out vec3 N;
out vec3 L;
out vec3 R;
out vec3 V;


uniform mat4 local2clip;
uniform mat4 local2eye;
uniform mat4 normal_matrix;
uniform mat4 world2eye; 

uniform vec4 light_ambient;
uniform vec4 light_diffuse;
uniform vec4 light_specular;
uniform vec4 light_pos;
#version 330 compatibility

uniform vec4 mat_ambient;
uniform vec4 mat_diffuse;
uniform vec4 mat_specular;
uniform float mat_shine; 

//varying vec3 v_normal;  // vertex normal 
out vec4 v_color;   // vertex color 
out vec4 pos_in_eye;  //vertex position in eye space 
out vec2 FtexCoord; 

void main(){

       gl_Position = local2clip * position;

       N =     normalize(vec3(normal_matrix * normal));    //v_normal
       vec4 Lpos =  world2eye * light_pos;                  //light pos. in eye
       vec4 Vpos =  local2eye * position;                   //pos_in_eye
       L = normalize(vec3(Lpos - Vpos));                    //light_vector

       R = normalize(reflect(-L, N)); 
       V = normalize(vec3(-Vpos));                          //eye vector

       vec3 halfv = normalize(L+V);
       FtexCoord = texCoord; 

       //pcolor = color1;
}
```

This is my FragemntShader

```
#version 330 compatibility

uniform int use_texture; 

in vec4 pcolor; 

in vec3 N1;
in vec3 L1;
in vec3 R1;
in vec3 V1;


uniform mat4 local2clip;
uniform mat4 local2eye;
uniform mat4 normal_matrix;
uniform mat4 world2eye; 

uniform vec4 light_ambient;
uniform vec4 light_diffuse;
uniform vec4 light_specular;
uniform vec4 light_pos;

uniform vec4 mat_ambient;
uniform vec4 mat_diffuse;
uniform vec4 mat_specular;
uniform float mat_shine;

uniform sampler2D Tex1; 
in vec2 FtexCoord1; 

void main() { 

       vec4 ambient = light_ambient * mat_ambient;
       float NdotL; 
       if (dot(N1,L1) <0.0) NdotL = 0.0; 
       else NdotL = dot(N1, L1); 

       vec4 diffuse = light_diffuse * mat_diffuse * NdotL;

       float RdotV; 
       RdotV = dot(R1, V1); 

       if (NdotL == 0.0) RdotV = 0.0; 
       if (RdotV <0.0) RdotV = 0.0; 

       vec4 specular = light_specular * mat_specular * pow(RdotV,mat_shine);   

       vec4 texcolor;


       if( use_texture == 1 ) {
          texcolor = texture2D(Tex1, FtexCoord1); 
          gl_FragColor = texcolor; 
       }
       else
          gl_FragColor = (diffuse + ambient + specular); 
 }
```

This is my GeometryShader

```
#version 330

layout (triangles) in;
layout (triangles) out;
layout (max_vertices = 3) out;

out vec3 N1;
out vec3 L1;
out vec3 R1;
out vec3 V1;

in vec3 N;
in vec3 L;
in vec3 R;
in vec3 V;

uniform mat4 local2clip;
uniform mat4 local2eye;
uniform mat4 normal_matrix;
uniform mat4 world2eye; 

uniform vec4 light_ambient;
uniform vec4 light_diffuse;
uniform vec4 light_specular;
uniform vec4 light_pos;

uniform vec4 mat_ambient;
uniform vec4 mat_diffuse;
uniform vec4 mat_specular;
uniform float mat_shine; 

//varying vec3 v_normal;  // vertex normal 
out vec4 v_color1;  // vertex color 
out vec4 pos_in_eye1;  //vertex position in eye space 
out vec2 FtexCoord1; 

in vec4 v_color;    // vertex color 
in vec4 pos_in_eye;  //vertex position in eye space 
in vec2 FtexCoord; 

void main(void)
{
    int i;
        N1=N;
        L1=L;
        R1=R;
        V1=R;

        FtexCoord1=FtexCoord;
        v_color1=v_color;
        pos_in_eye1=pos_in_eye;



    for (i = 0; i < gl_in.length(); i++)
    {


        gl_Position = gl_in[i].gl_Position;
        EmitVertex();
    }
    EndPrimitive();
}
```

I just want that what ever was there earlier is passed from vertex shader to fragment shader via geometry shader, so that I can manipulate the shader later. Currently the screen is just black

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The core of your problem is that you didn't bother to check for compilation errors when you built your Geometry Shader. I know that because I see several syntax errors for it. In particular:

```
in vec3 N;
in vec3 L;
in vec3 R;
in vec3 V;

in vec4 v_color;    // vertex color 
in vec4 pos_in_eye;  //vertex position in eye space 
in vec2 FtexCoord;
```

[Geometry Shader inputs](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Geometry_Shader#Inputs) are *always* aggregated into arrays. Remember: a geometry shader operates on *[primitives](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Primitive)*, which are defined as a collection of one or more vertices. Each GS invocation therefore gets a set of per-vertex input values, one for each vertex in the [primitive type defined by your `layout in` qualifier](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Geometry_Shader#Primitive_in.2Fout_specification).

Notice how you loop over the number of vertices in a primitive and use `gl_in[i]` to get the input value for each vertex in the primitive. That's how you need to access *all* of your Geometry Shader inputs. And you need to write each one to its corresponding output variable, then call `EmitVertex`. All in that loop.

Comment: I have made some changes and it works, but I have added pics, there is a difference what I used to get and what I get now.

Comment: @BhavyaArora: BTW, You should read [Stack Overflow policy on follow-up questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290746/follow-on-question-vs-edit-to-original-when-to-use-which).

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, I wasn't aware of this. I will follow up on the new one. I will be glad if you can help me in that. :)