# Light changes with Pass Through Geometry Shader

Tags: opengl, glsl, geometry-shader

[image]

I am using FragmentShader and VertexShader at present, and works absolutely fine. I cannot get my geometry shader working proprly. I am absolutely new to it, below is what I have tried.

I am using VBO, lighting and textures along with some geometry, but it works fine before using GeometryShader. The only thing I have changed is the variable names as I had to get the input in the geometry shader and give the output. So I have appended 1 at the end of those variable names those which will go out from geometry shader to the fragment shader.

Also I have added headers starting with # which were earlier not there. I am using GL_TRIANGLES to draw.

VertexShader

```
uniform mat4 local2clip;
uniform mat4 local2eye;
uniform mat4 normal_matrix;
uniform mat4 world2eye; 

uniform vec4 light_ambient;
uniform vec4 light_diffuse;
uniform vec4 light_specular;
uniform vec4 light_pos;


uniform vec4 mat_ambient;
uniform vec4 mat_diffuse;
uniform vec4 mat_specular;
uniform float mat_shine; 

//varying vec3 v_normal;  // vertex normal 
out vec2 FtexCoord; 

void main(){

       gl_Position = local2clip * position;

       N =     normalize(vec3(normal_matrix * normal));    //v_normal
       vec4 Lpos =  world2eye * light_pos;                  //light pos. in eye
       vec4 Vpos =  local2eye * position;                   //pos_in_eye
       L = normalize(vec3(Lpos - Vpos));                    //light_vector

       R = normalize(reflect(-L, N)); 
       V = normalize(vec3(-Vpos));                          //eye vector

       vec3 halfv = normalize(L+V);
       FtexCoord = texCoord; 

       //pcolor = color1;
}
```

This is my FragmentShader

```
#version 330 compatibility

uniform int use_texture; 

in vec4 pcolor; 

in vec3 N1;
in vec3 L1;
in vec3 R1;
in vec3 V1;


uniform mat4 local2clip;
uniform mat4 local2eye;
uniform mat4 normal_matrix;
uniform mat4 world2eye; 

uniform vec4 light_ambient;
uniform vec4 light_diffuse;
uniform vec4 light_specular;
uniform vec4 light_pos;

uniform vec4 mat_ambient;
uniform vec4 mat_diffuse;
uniform vec4 mat_specular;
uniform float mat_shine;

uniform sampler2D Tex1; 
in vec2 FtexCoord1; 

void main() { 

       vec4 ambient = light_ambient * mat_ambient;
       float NdotL; 
       if (dot(N1,L1) <0.0) NdotL = 0.0; 
       else NdotL = dot(N1, L1); 

       vec4 diffuse = light_diffuse * mat_diffuse * NdotL;

       float RdotV; 
       RdotV = dot(R1, V1); 

       if (NdotL == 0.0) RdotV = 0.0; 
       if (RdotV <0.0) RdotV = 0.0; 

       vec4 specular = light_specular * mat_specular * pow(RdotV,mat_shine);   

       vec4 texcolor;


       if( use_texture == 1 ) {
          texcolor = texture2D(Tex1, FtexCoord1); 
          gl_FragColor = texcolor; 
       }
       else
          gl_FragColor = (diffuse + ambient + specular); 
 }
```

This is my Geometry Shader

```
#version 330

layout (triangles) in;
layout (triangle_strip, max_vertices = 3) out;

out vec3 N1;
out vec3 L1;
out vec3 R1;
out vec3 V1;

in vec3 N[3];
in vec3 L[3];
in vec3 R[3];
in vec3 V[3];

uniform mat4 local2clip;
uniform mat4 local2eye;
uniform mat4 normal_matrix;
uniform mat4 world2eye; 

uniform vec4 light_ambient;
uniform vec4 light_diffuse;
uniform vec4 light_specular;
uniform vec4 light_pos;

uniform vec4 mat_ambient;
uniform vec4 mat_diffuse;
uniform vec4 mat_specular;
uniform float mat_shine; 

//varying vec3 v_normal;  // vertex normal 
out vec2 FtexCoord1; 

in vec2 FtexCoord[3]; 

void main(void)
{
    int i;



    for (i = 0; i < gl_in.length(); i++)
    {
        N1=N[i];
        L1=L[i];
        R1=R[i];
        V1=R[i];

        FtexCoord1=FtexCoord[i]; 

        gl_Position = gl_in[i].gl_Position;
        EmitVertex();
    }
    EndPrimitive();
}
```

I just want that what ever was there earlier is passed from vertex shader to fragment shader via geometry shader, so that I can manipulate the shader later. But the light is not showing the same effect.As shown in the pics.

Comment: The only reason I'm not marking this as a duplicate of your previous question is because you changed [your previous one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34112683/passthrough-geometry-shader-not-working) to be a completely different question. So I'll revert it back, and leave this one as a separate question that stands alone.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Thanks for letting me know. The shine due to the specular has changed. Don't know why is that happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a small bug in the code.It should be `V1=V[i];` Instead of `V1=R[i];`